# the error is 'int' object is not iterable, I am working on a small project in python that allows the user to input ten names and ten ages of students

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
print("\n")
print("Please input ten student names and their ages as well")
print("\n")
print("Student Names: \t\t\t\t Student Ages: ")
print("------------------- \t\t\t\t -------------------")
print("\n")
studentNames =[]
for element in range(10):
    element = input("Please input 10 student names: ")
    input_ages = int(input("\t\t\t\t\tNow please input their ages as well: "))

team_leader = max(input_ages)

print(team_leader)
```

Comment: I am trying to write a program that asks for the names and ages of 10 students.
Then the program prints the names and ages of the students alphabetically in a table format
while also identifying the oldest student as the "Team Leader". and I need help in doing so please respond any information will help also I am a  moderate user of Python I know some but I am not an expert

Comment: You should read the How to Ask page to understand what good/proper questions look like.

Comment: What are you doing with `studentNames`? (Hint: you will need to use this somehow inside the loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for element in range(10):
>     ...
>     input_ages = int(input("\t\t\t\t\tNow please input their ages as well: "))
>
> team_leader = max(input_ages)
> ```

`input_ages` is a single integer that gets reassigned each loop iteration.

`max(input_ages)` expects `input_ages` to be a list for which to find the maximum value by iterating over it. Therefore you get `'int' object is not iterable`.

To do it correctly, initialize an empty list `input_ages` before the loop, and then append the ages to that list in the loop:

```
input_ages = []
for element in range(10):
    ...
    input_ages.append(int(input("\t\t\t\t\tNow please input their ages as well: ")))

team_leader = max(input_ages)
```

Comment: But then your program will still not work correctly...

Comment: ok that helped a lot mkrieger1 I appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written it does:

```
Displays info
Makes empty list studentsNames
Repeats the following 10 times:
 Asks the user for ten names and put the string in a variable
 Asks the user for the ten ages and tries to turn a string to an integer* and stores that in a variable
 Each loop, the variables are overwritten
Gets the highest value from the age variable which would be the last and only one, saves it to a variable
Display that variable
```

*You must input each student one a loop or it would have you are error.

However you would want to do something like this, i think. I have continues to use two lists but I think there would be a better way to store the data.

```
print("your info")
names = []
ages = []
for __ in range(10):
    name.append(input("Enter student name: "))
    age.append(int(input("Age: ")))
oldest_age = max(ages)
index = ages.index[oldest_age]
team_leader = names[index]
print(team_leader)
```